# Fire callback when drawing a sprite tile to draw new layer over tile

Tags: createjs

Is there a way to add a callback to a sprite, so as whenever it is displayed on screen another sprite is drawn over this?  (This is to draw a larger sprite over the current sprite).

I have to add that I'm fairly new to createjs.

Answer (score 0):

Actually got this fixed by detecting the specific sprite early enough and having that function add a layer to draw over the other.

Another way to do this is to add an event listener to the specific sprite and create a layer on top of the other.